# Background animations

Tags: javascript, css

Im a beginner in a web dev and im fascinated by sophisticated yet simple animations and how to make them :)
Let's take a look at the example here : [risingstack](https://community.risingstack.com/)
The nav bar is soo cool with that infinite animation. From what i see in the inspector it's a css transition[?], but i don't really understand it and here's my 1st question: How to achieve that! (im not expecting a full tut from you, just point me in the right direction ) I will appreciate any valuable materials!

..and a 2nd question is: Can we make background animations with JS? (coz if we put some code in a loop it will block any event listeners etc right ?)

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question will likely be closed, as it seems to violate quite a few of the posting rules. As a suggestion, do some independent research, try to make it yourself, and if your attempt doesn't succeed - come here, include the attempt, and we'll tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: That site is not using css transitions.  That header is made from a canvas element.  It's likely built from scratch using javascript.

Comment: @Santi sorry for that, and thanks for the edit.

Comment: @JosephMarikle hm a canvas then.. i will look into this, thanks!

Comment: Not an issue, keep it in mind for next time. My edit simply removed the tags from your title, as there's already a tagging system in place - no need to replicate them in the title as well. The How To Ask link I posted in my original comment includes how titles should be formatted as well. Good luck.